# how to store data that is receieved to webserver from arduino

Tags: php, asp.net, webserver, port

Since i didnt do any webserver code so far,my mind is full of questions.Lets say I have web server and I want to store data that comes from an arduino in database.How can I receive data ? Do I have to use php,write a script for webserver.Lets say I write the script and I made server to listen the port,where should I put script in my server in order to make server listen the port all the time.I need a tutorial.Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is way to broad a question, I'm really not even sure what Arduino is? but I found this in like 15 seconds on google, http://arduinotronics.blogspot.com/2015/12/sending-sensor-data-to-web-server.html  In short you would have to post it to the webserver, think like a form submission, or a REST api.

Comment: Thanks for your concern I'm going to look at it

Comment: Sure, my google skillz are un-matched....

Comment: hahaha.Good one :D

Answer (score 0):

I already did something like you want to do, and today I think the best choice is to do a [REST api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming) on an external webserver (you can do it with PHP). You can also install you API (or any other kind of program) on your arduino but you will be limited by the memory (depending the amount of data you write).